# Avoid URL-encoding in XSLT with output method html

Tags: html, xslt-1.0, urlencode

I have a transformation that outputs HTML. In order to avoid self-closing tags that could break in older browsers (e.g. `<img />` instead of `<img></img>`) output-method has to be `html`. Then though URL-encoding is applied so that it breaks my application. See for example:

**Input**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{{example}}
<a href="{{example}}" >abc</a>
<img src="http://placehold.it/20x20"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

**Transformation**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" /><!-- either -->
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" /><!-- or -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

In the first case the output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
{{example}}
<a href="{{example}}">abc</a>
<img src="http://placehold.it/20x20"/>
</body>
</html>
```

In the second case the output is:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
{{example}}
<a href="%7B%7Bexample%7D%7D">abc</a>
<img src="http://placehold.it/20x20">
</body>
</html>
```

What is good about the first case is that the `@href` attribute is **not URL-encoded**. This is a must for my application. What is bad though and better achieved by the second variant is, that the `<img>` is self-closing. This must not be for `<img>` tags and some others.

Is there a way to have the benefits of `method="html"` without the URL-encoding? If yes, how?

Comment: I suspect this may depend on the processor. Which one are you using? Though the percent encoding is correct in this case - the `href` of an `a` in HTML must be a valid URI. Is it an option to use `((example))` instead of `{{example}}` as parentheses _are_ allowed in a URI?

Comment: I am using PHPs http://de3.php.net/manual/en/class.xsltprocessor.php class but a Java based processor might be used in the future as well. Using a different style of brackets is a good idea, but I am not sure whether or not this will work with our current application. Thank you, though!

Comment: Are you sure self-closing tags (vs unclosed tags) break older browsers? I was under the impression _really_ old browsers just treated `/` as an attribute name when preceded by a space.

Comment: @Eric I am not sure whether they break all or especially really old browsers, but there are at least some rendering engines that I need to support which are picky about them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using PHP's XSLT 1.0 processor, then you might try the following solution...

1. Use method="html";
2. Include this template...

   ```
   <xsl:template match="@href">
     <xsl:attribute name="Muttaburrasaurus">
       <xsl:value-of select="." />
     </xsl:attribute>
   </xsl:template>
   ```
3. Load the resultant output into a string, and replace all occurrences of `Muttaburrasaurus` with `href`.

If you migrate to Java in the future, as you indicated in the comment feed that you might do so, then ensure that your processor is XSLT 2.0+. Then you can use the `escape-uri-attributes` feature as mentioned by M.Kay .

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0 you can suppress %-encoding of URL attributes using the serialization option escape-uri-attributes="no". There is no equivalent in XSLT 1.0.