# How to disable html uri escaping in xslt transformming?

Tags: php, html, xml, xslt, uri

The requirement is to transform a data xml file into html template, and then use this template to generate actual page, to be embedded in emails.

So let's look at the following example:

XML data file (test.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xslt"?>
<url><![CDATA[http://www.example.net/testurl/{{value1}}?{{value2}}&{{value3}}]]></url>
```

XSLT file (test.xslt):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" version="1.0"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:value-of select="/url" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            Click
        </a>
    </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Server script (test.php)

```
<?php
   $xslDoc = new DOMDocument();
   $xslDoc->load("test.xslt");

   $xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
   $xmlDoc->load("test.xml");

   $proc = new XSLTProcessor();
   $proc->importStylesheet($xslDoc);
   echo $proc->transformToXML($xmlDoc);
?>
```

When the above .php file executes, the result is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"></head>
<body><a href="http://www.example.net/testurl/%7B%7Bvalue1%7D%7D?%7B%7Bvalue2%7D%7D&amp;%7B%7Bvalue3%7D%7D">
            Click
        </a></body>
</html>
```

Notice the `href` property is encoded, which is not compatible with our existing code that fills in the placeholders (i.e. `{{value1}}` etc).

How to avoid the encoding so that our existing code can work?

Comment: Have you tried this without CDATA block in XML template (but with `&` in the parameter string properly encoded as `&amp;`? Just wondering if you get same problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Avoid URL-encoding in XSLT with output method html](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185948/avoid-url-encoding-in-xslt-with-output-method-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an issue of output escaping but url-encoding. This is done because libxml2 recognizes that this is an `href` and does the required percent-encoding on the url.

Short story is that this is not under the xslt-template's control. You will need to fix it via post-processing.

This should cover the `<a href="">` case, but there may be other attributes that libxml2 percent-encodes.

```
$xformed = $proc->transformToDoc($xslDoc);
$xp = new DOMXPath($xformed);
$urls = $xp->query('descendant::a/@href');
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $url->value = urldecode($url->value);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a switch in XSLT 2.0 (in xsl:output) to disable %HH-encoding of URL attribute values, but unfortunately you are using XSLT 1.0, which has no equivalent.

One approach might be a pipeline that first transforms to XML, then executes your "existing code that fills in the placeholders (i.e. {{value1}} etc).", then converts to HTML.

Answer (score -2):

```
disable-output-escaping="yes"
```

should help you out in this case.

Specifically, used [like this](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_value-of.asp).

To summarise the comments:

```
<xsl:element name="a">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="/url" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:element>
```

Comment: `disable-output-escaping="yes"` is good for `xsl:text` nodes. However, I cannot use in within a `xsl:attribute` node. Can you show me how?

Comment: um, `<xsl:attribute name="whatever"><xsl:value-of select="whatever" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></xsl:attribute>`

Comment: exactly. so in your case, it would be `<xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:value-of select="/url" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
            </xsl:attribute>`

Comment: Thanks, I have tried, but it does not seems to help. The output is still encoded.

Comment: Arar, that is because I was trying something else: use a `<xsl:element name="a">` tag instead. So can you update the answer with the above clarification and then I can mark it.

Comment: assuming I understood your comment correctly, that should be it.

Comment: Hi, I found that if I use any attribute names other than `href` the `disalbe-out-escaping` is working. However, whenever I change the attribute name to `href` then it become encoded. So this is NOT solving the problem.

Comment: WRONG ANSWER. disable-output-escaping has no effect on attribute nodes. The spec is quite explicit on this point.