# Input Textbox value not replacing &lt; with < in xsl

Tags: html, xml, xslt, replace, entityreference

display-name is not displaying < correctly instead it displays as `&lt;`.
In view-source it appears as `&amp;lt;` 
I want that to display properly. 
I tried in many ways but doing in back end and in the java code its providing error saying premature end of function for me.

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="@display-name ='' ">
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="DISPLAY_NAME" VALUE="{para-description}" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:when test="para-description ='' ">
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="DISPLAY_NAME" VALUE="{@name}" />
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="DISPLAY_NAME" VALUE="{@display-name}" />
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: You have an output encoding issue. Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185948/avoid-url-encoding-in-xslt-with-output-method-html

Comment: Can you please post the exact answer for my prob  here .. I'm not getting it ..

Comment: I am not sure of the answer. If you want to have an output of `VALUE="|<OOl_ |</\T"` You may have invalid HTML -  If the view-source is `&amp;&amp;lt;` you might have escaped it too many times. Can you show the output?

Comment: The output coming in view source is like &amp;lt; for <

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSL - How to disable output escaping for an attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921123/xsl-how-to-disable-output-escaping-for-an-attribute)

Comment: Please post enough code (XML + XSLT) to enable us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: this is xml code for this xslt .. formed using java as a string and returned to it ..
("<parametric-def id=\"" + header_uid + "\" "
                              + "name=\"" + parametricname + "\" "
                              + "display-name=\"" + displayname + "\" "
                         +"search_flg=\"" + searchFlag+"\">"
                              + "<para-description>" + parametricdesc + "</para-description>"
        + "</parametric-def>");

and its passed to the xslt ... where its used there as i was mentioned in my question